# Are top and bottom plates required for a furring strip wall?

Tags: framing

I'm going to be framing out a wall in my basement by using 2x2 furring strips, attaching them with Tapcon screws to the masonry block so that I can hang the drywall onto and also give me a little room for foam insulation.

I can't use 2x4 because it would run into my vents and I don't want to add repositioning the vents to this project.

Since I’m just framing this to hang a few sheets of drywall, can I get away without having to use a top and bottom plate or is that asking for drywall cracks down the road?

Comment: Seems a small price to pay for extra stability and structure.  Required, maybe not, but what's a few extra 2x2's and some cuts?

Comment: If you don’t use plates I would use corner bead at the top and make sure to nail the bottom trim to the studs.

Comment: I'd leave the top plate out before I left the bottom plate out.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the furring strips on the top and bottom so you have something to nail the drywall to otherwise it is going to warp. It cannot span 4 feet with no support.

Comment: 4 feet? Where does that come from?

Comment: Very valid point that drywall won't span 4 feet without support, but I'm also confused where you got that measurement from...

Comment: I think @user1946891 is forgetting that there should be 2 furring "studs" between each edge of the drywall panels.